# Use WCF service at the same manner as with local class library

Tags: c#, wcf

I would like to work with WCF service at the same manner as with local class library.

### For example:

```
// SystemLogin oLogin = new SystemLogin();                                    // create object instance from class library
ServiceReference1.SystemLogin oLogin = new ServiceReference1.SystemLogin();   // create object instance from WCF-service
oLogin.Login = "Login";                                                       // set property No. 1
oLogin.Password = "Password";                                                 // set property No. 2
oLogin.Connect();                                                             // call method
```

---

Is it possible at all? If yes, how will WCF contract looks like ?

Comment: Have you tried creating the service reference and calling it in this manner?

Comment: In case your service implementation is reachable from your code you can easily create an instance. But normally you write services in order to call them from other places to decouple caller and recipient. I think your problem is, that you dont want to write some "boilerplate" code everytime you want to access an service. You can search for "service discovery" and use some best practices to get your services.

Answer (score 0):

My question in another words. I have a simple class library (2 properties, 1 method) and wanna use it on WCF-service with little changing of my Win-app functionality:

> // create object instance from WCF-service
>
> ServiceReference1.SystemLogin oLogin = new
>   ServiceReference1.SystemLogin();
>
> // instead of
>
> // create object instance from class library
>
> SystemLogin oLogin = new SystemLogin();

How will WCF contract looks like ?

Example of class library:

> ```
> class SystemLogin
> {
>
>     private string login;
>     private string password;
>
>     public SystemLogin()
>     {
>         this.login = "";
>         this.password = "";
>     }
>
>     public int Connect()
>     {
>         return 1;
>     }
>
>     public string Login
>     {
>         get { return login; }
>         set { login = value; }
>     }
>
>     public string Password
>     {
>         get { return password; }
>         set { password = value; }
>     }
> ```